# Ruby RI fails with instance of RDoc::Context::Section needs to have method `marshal_load' (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rdoc, ri

I am running **Rails 3.2.14** under *Ruby 2.0.0 (rvm) on OSX*. When I attempt to access the ri documentation for most methods, I get the following stack trace.

**stack trace:**

```
/Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/store.rb:196:in `load': instance of RDoc::Context::Section needs to have method `marshal_load' (TypeError)
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/store.rb:196:in `block in load_class'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/store.rb:195:in `open'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/store.rb:195:in `load_class'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:609:in `block in classes_and_includes_for'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:607:in `map'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:607:in `classes_and_includes_for'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:681:in `display_class'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:712:in `display_name'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:739:in `block in display_names'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:736:in `each'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:736:in `display_names'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:1137:in `run'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:320:in `run'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/gems/rdoc-3.12.2/bin/ri:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/bin/ri:23:in `load'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/bin/ri:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/daryl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@deals/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I believe that the problem relates to Ruby 2 defaulting to *RDoc 4.0*, while the bundler environment is using *RDoc 3.12.2* due to dependencies:

```
journey-1.0.4 depends on rdoc (~> 3.11, development)
journey-1.0.4 depends on rdoc (~> 3.10, development)
tilt-1.4.1 depends on rdoc (>= 0, development)
tilt-1.4.1 depends on rdoc (>= 0, development)
mail-2.5.4 depends on rdoc (>= 0, development)
rdoc-3.12.2 depends on rdoc (~> 3.10, development)
railties-3.2.14 depends on rdoc (~> 3.4)
kaminari-0.14.1 depends on rdoc (>= 0, development)
arel-3.0.2 depends on rdoc (~> 3.10, development)
nokogiri-1.6.0 depends on rdoc (~> 3.10, development)
launchy-2.3.0 depends on rdoc (~> 3.12, development)
oauth2-0.8.1 depends on rdoc (>= 0, development)
sqlite3-1.3.7 depends on rdoc (~> 3.10, development)
uglifier-2.1.1 depends on rdoc (>= 3.11, development)
```

My guess is that when gem generates the ri documentation, it is using *rdoc 4.0.0* but then *3.12.2* is being used to try and read it. I have no issue accessing the documentation outside the context of my Rails project.

Any suggestions? I'm guessing this may no longer be an issue in *Rails 4*, but that isn't really an option at the moment.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up biting the bullet and upgrading to *Rails 4*, which completely resolved the issue. The gem dependencies for *Rails 4* and *Ruby 2.0.0* are lined up.

For anyone interested in using RI without the option of upgrading to *Rails 4*, I'd recommend sticking with *Ruby 1.9.3*; this includes *RDoc 3.12.2*, which is compatible with the above *Rails 3.2.14* dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This probably means your missing [the correct version] of the rdoc gem.  Try `gem install rdoc`.